# Fancybox 1.3.4 - Show Title with multiple <BR> Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, fancybox, title

I am trying to modify a theme with Fancybox 1.3.4 and I am having a really hard time. Right now Fancybox displays a title ie; 'Image x of x'

This can be seen here:

http://leahyerpe.com/exhibit/paintings/

Here is the script from the js.options.php in regards to the title:

```
function(title, currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts) { 
                            return '<div class="gallery-image-title">' + (title && title.length ? '<strong>' + title + '</strong>' : '' ) + '<span class="image-count">Image ' + (currentIndex + 1) + ' of ' + currentArray.length + '</span></div>';
    }, 
    'onComplete'    :   function(){
        jQuery("#fancybox-close").hide();
        jQuery("#fancybox-title").hide();
        jQuery("#fancybox-wrap").hover(function() {
            jQuery("#fancybox-close").stop(true).fadeTo("fast", 1.0);
            jQuery("#fancybox-title").stop(true).fadeTo("fast", 1.0);
        }, function() {
            jQuery("#fancybox-close").stop(true).fadeTo("fast", 0);
            jQuery("#fancybox-title").stop(true).fadeTo("fast", 0);
        });
    }
});
```

What I am trying to do is remove the 'Image x of x' title and replace it with a title that has breaks in it, ie:

'Title of the image'
'Another Piece of info'
'Third Piece of Info'

Is this possible? Right now I can't even get the Title attribute to
display when I insert one in wordpress, all I can get to display is
the 'Image x of x'.

Thanks so much.
J

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like that in the fancybox setup:

```
...
'showTitle' : true,
'titlePosition' : 'over',
'titleFormat': function(title, currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts){
...
return '<div>'+info1+'</br>'+info2+'</br>'+info3+'</div>'},
....
```

Where info1, info2, info3 are the data you would like to publish. Of course you can add necessary formaiing etc.